# Is it possible to decrypt Wireshark packages using web browser certificates?

Tags: ssl, wireshark, encryption

it seams that, if using HTTPS protocol, packages transferred between browser and web server are all encrypted. And all the browser has to support its communication session with web server is so called certificates.

So I think it's clear that we can use the same certificates to decrypt packages that captured by Wireshark during the login of HTTPS sites.

I googled, and find some tutorials said the private key should be supplied, which i do think impossible and unpractical.

BTW. the following shell command get certificate from host , are there tools to yield the public key?

```
echo QUIT | openssl s_client -connect <site>:443 | sed -ne '/BEGIN CERT/,/END CERT/p'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot decrypt HTTPS/SSL sessions from a network capture, even if you do have the certificates. That is the whole point of [Public Key Cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) on which SSL is based.

What you have in your browser key-store is the certificates that will verify the validity of the public keys of the server. Said public keys are accessible, but they cannot be used to decrypt the session packets because the encryption algorithm is not symmetric.

You would need the *private* keys of the *server* in order to descrypt an SSL session and in normal situations it is quite hard to acquire those.

See also the Wikipedia article on [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) for more information.

EDIT:

I will add some more information in layman terms, mostly ripped off from the two links above, to make things a bit more clear.

Public Key Cryptography is based on asymmetric encryption algorithms. Those involve *two* keys, rather than one, a public key and a private key. Those two keys consist a *key pair*. Assuming a sufficiently strong algorithm, whatever is encrypted with the public key can only be encrypted with the private one and vice versa. The public key is widely accessible to "everyone" while the private key is stored securely and only used by its owner. How does this help?

- The server has a key pair that consists of a world-readable public key and a securely stored (and inaccessible to anyone but the server itself) private key.
- The client uses the server's *public* key to encrypt a rather long random key for a symmetric algorithm at the start of each encrypted session. That key is sent to the server.
- Since the symmetric key is encrypted like this, it can only be decrypted using the server's *private* key. That means that it cannot be extracted from a captured network stream, and since it is used for the rest of the session, neither can any of the information that is transmitted later on.
- The server uses its private key to retrieve the session symmetric key and all is well.

Is it? There is still one issue in the above scheme! How will the client get the server's public key? More specifically how does it know that it speaks with the server proper, and not some crook who managed to insert themselves in the middle (See [Man In The Middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack))?

The client cannot possibly know every single public key - there are millions of them. It will have to retrieve them from the servers and then somehow make sure they belong to the server they are interested in.

This is where another function of Public Key Cryptography comes in. Previously we used the public key to encrypt data so that only its intended destination could descrypt it. Now we
do the opposite: We use the *private* key to encrypt data so that it can only be decrypted with the public key. Essentially we *sign* the data so that if decrypts with the public key people will know the data came from the server. How does this help?

When the browser is installed it has a relatively small number of public keys (commonly known as certificates) pre-installed. Those belong to Certification Authorities (CA) that are entities (generally companies like Verisign, governments or even some Institutions) that are deemed trustworthy. The Certification Authorities use the corresponding private keys to *sign* other public keys available in the Internet and so on.

So when the browser contacts a server and receives its public key, that key should be signed with the private key from a certificate pair. That certificate pair would be likewise be signed by another and so on, *until* the browser comes up to a public key that was signed with the private key that corresponds to one of the Root Certificates that were preinstalled with it. You might want to read a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269934/openssl-chain-of-issuer-certificates/4270366#4270366) for more on Root Certificates, or just read the Wikipedia articles.

Since each public key was successively signed until we reached a trusted key, the client can now be certain that the server on the other end of the connection is indeed e.g. MyBank.com and not, say, some criminal's laptop in the next cafe table that is messing with the wireless connection.

While there have been weak SSL algorithms (hence the succession of SSL protocol versions), these days the attacks are generally targeted to the implementations:

- Use specially crafted or malformed certificates to fool the browser (and its weak implementation) into thinking that a public key is signed by a trusted entity when it's really not.
- Compromise the integrity of the client software (e.g. a virus) to capture the symmetric keys when they are generated. In most of those cases however, it is usually easier to just capture the interesting data as they are entered into the browser by e.g. capturing the keyboard strokes as the user types in their credit card number.
- Compromise the server itself and steal the private key. While it's not as easy as targeting unsuspecting clients, it has happened and it has the potential to compromise a significantly larger number of encrypted sessions. The current [Public Key Infrastructure (PKI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) has a whole mechanism for the revocation and disabling of compromised or otherwise invalid keys.

The last attack can be defeated if the client sends a temporary public key of its own instead of a symmetric key and use an asymmetric algorithm for the whole session. That would make it impossible for an attacker to compromise past sessions by stealing the server's private key. This technique is the basis for ensuring [Perfect Forward Secrecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_forward_secrecy), but unfortunately not all servers implement it yet due to compatibility or performance reasons.

Comment: @Andre White: please read up on Public Key Cryptography before commenting. The browser has the server's per-session public key and this allows it to decrypt the packets that the server encrypts using its per-session private key. The per-session server public key is encrypted with the server private key when it is sent to the browser, therefore a network sniffer cannot compromise it. You would have to compromise the browser itself (e.g. spyware) to do that.

Comment: @thkala, I deleted my original comment since it was clearly wrong and set a wrong tone. It is early and I was thinking he had full access to the browser (so he could see the symmetric keys used once the asymmetric key exchange was done).

Comment: @thkala, Confused. Since the browser can decrypt the package, as you mentioned, by means of certificates(public key), why wireshark can't. Does the browser  encrypt the certificates? And what kind of spyware can do such a thing, may you be kind to share some?

Comment: @thkala, I think its time to broaden my knowledge, I will finish your link.

Comment: @user435657: The server (or the client I can't remember) actually creates DES/AES keys using the the keys associated with the cert. However, that key is only used for a small window of the data transfer and then it is erased and it is usually only stored in memory as needed and only sent over the wire if encrypted with the servers public key.

Comment: @thkala, Yes, RSA is time consuming and is only used to encrypt session keys of symmetric algorithm. And the later packages are all encrypted based on the symmetric key.

Comment: Well I see, it's the client who generates the session key, so the certificates do no help to decrypt the packages.

Answer (score 0):

thkala is spot on. You can, assuming you have MiTM, under common circumstances forward a self signed certificate to the victim for which you have the private key, then forward the requests by the victim to the destination server using the servers' real certificate. This will require the vicitm to accept a certificate warning though.

Another way of defeating Ssl is by stripping the ssl session, lookup sslstrip.